# How to get the details of all the resoures from their resource groups

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to set up an azure logic-app with an azure function that will get all(most) of details of all the resources in a subscription. including their subscription ID, Resource Guid and the resource group they reside

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is to make use of the `Azure Resource Management` API's to operate on your resources. For your requirement you can make use of the below.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?api-version=2019-05-10
```

Remember you need to pass your `bearer_token` along with your Request Headers. To know on how to get a bearer token read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-configure-postman)

More information on ARM API's - [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list)